# Controller setup problem with pre-owned game

Tags: controllers, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

My pre-owned game setup is in Southpaw or left-handed mode.  I cannot get it to default to right-handed.  It continues to default to left-handed or Legacy Southpaw.  How do I revert it to right-handed rather than left-handed?

Comment: ... what game is it? What platform are you playing it on?

Comment: need for info on the game/platform, but usually the settings in the game is what would have the controller settings. If the settings are saved to the game itself.. we can assume its not a modern game.. as games nowadays are saved to the console.

Comment: Ironically, the first controller was designed by a leftie for himself, making 'southpaw' mode in games a bit of a misnomer. </trivia>